# Present perfect or simple past with "for the last twenty minutes"?

Tags: present-perfect, time, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

My teacher  give me a question

> You know she (stand)______ looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes.

and my job is complete this sentence with any verb tense provided it makes sense.

My teacher said it must be present perfect:

> You know **she has stood** looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes.

But I think the simple past is correct:

> You know **she stood** looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes.

It seems to me "for the last twenty minutes" is a completed time period, it can't include the present moment. So we can't use the present perfect.

Can you explain to me which is correct?

Comment: You can definitely use present perfect. And if she is still looking at the picture, it's definitely the tense I would expect. (But if she's not still looking at the picture, both simple past and present perfect work fine.)

Comment: (1) "You know she has stood looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes." is not right. (2) "You know she has been standing [and] looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes." is better. (3) "last 20 minutes" may or may not include the present moment. (4) your completion is also valid. (5) some teachers do not like students who disagree, so better to go along, atleast to get the grades.

Comment: related : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/311625/we-have-stood-and-using-correct-tense-with-the-tone-of-an-article

Comment: *“You know what? She’s been standing there looking at picture for twenty minutes now!”*

Comment: Peter's and Prem's answers are at variance. This is possibly a US - non-US difference regarding idiomaticity. As a Brit, I prefer 'has been standing  looking ...' though as it's clunky, I'd echo tchrist. With the 'that' that's still in his word-processor.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , my suggestion (marked (2) in my earlier comment) is almost the same as what you & tchrist suggest; I only used the optional [and] to split the words "standing" and "looking" , whereas, tchrist used "there" to split. [[ I think putting "you know what?" may change the sentence too much; EG If I had said that I did not know she had seen my picture, somebody may claim "you know she has been ...."; Here "you know what? ..." may not make sense as a rebuttal. More-over, OP wants to fill in the blank, not rephrase the sentence ]]

Comment: @Edwin: even as an American, I slightly prefer *"has been standing looking."* But I wouldn't say *has stood looking* is wrong in any way. And *was standing* works, too.

Comment: @Prem 'You can definitely use present perfect.' and  ' "You know she has stood looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes." is not right.' are what are contradictory.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , yes, I agree about that contradiction, which you rightly guess is "US - non-US"; I was only responding to the next sentence of your earlier comment "As a Brit, I prefer .... echo tchrist"

Comment: @Prem So ' "You know she has stood looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes." is not right.' is not right. It should be  ' "You know she has stood looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes." sounds less acceptable to Brits.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , I am not able to edit my earliest comment , but I would rephrase **is not right** as **is not my preference , because it sounds wrong or odd to me** ; Now , I think all of us ( Prem , Edwin , tchrist , Peter ) seem to **prefer** the common variant **has been standing**. Anyway , I hope OP got what he wanted to know. Well , let us move on . . . .

Comment: If I were you, I would use present perfect continuous. You know she has been standing (and) looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes (until now and so on).

Comment: Come on now: most English speakers would say: stand staring at the picture and not stand looking at the picture. I submit that looking here is weird. Also, "the **last** 20 minutes" triggers the present prefect or PPC  on both sides of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would use present perfect continuous.

> You know she has been standing (and) looking at that picture for the last twenty minutes (until now and so on).